# Import file and convert integers into int

Tags: list, python-2.7, python-import

I'm running into the following problem.
I import a file that looks like [[58, 59, 60]].
Printing it gives  ['[[58, 59, 60]]'].
Now I only want to add 58 59 60 to a new list. The problem is:

```
output gives ['[[58, 59, 60]]']
output[0] gives '[[58, 59, 60]]'
output[0][2] gives '5'
output[0][3] gives '8'.
```

Is there a way of importing the file in a way that it only loads full integers?

```
with open('file', 'r') as fobj:
     content = int(fobj.read())
```

Comment: Can you show us how you load your file ? You use a context manager ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, 'import a file'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use json to do the converting from string to actual list when reading from the file.

For example:

```
import json

def get_output(filename):     # filename is name of text file
    with open(filename) as fn:
        output = json.loads(fn.read())
        return output
```

If the file 't.txt' contains this: `[[58, 59, 60]]`, then `get_output('t.txt')` returns the list `[[58, 59, 60]]`:

```
output = get_output('t.txt')
type(output)       # ===> list
output[0]          # ===> [58, 59, 60]
output[0][2]       # ===> 60
```